# Dynamic GString creation doesn't not work as I expect

Tags: java, groovy, gstring

I have the following code:

```
def test( name  ) {
    s = ['$','{','n','a','m','e','}'].join()
    println s instanceof String // is true, s is not a gstring
    // create a GString 
    g = GString.EMPTY.plus( s )

    println g instanceof GString 
    println g.toString() // Shouldn't evaluate here? 
}
test("Oscar")
```

I expect the output to be:

```
true
true
Oscar
```

But instead I have:

```
true
true
${name}
```

I know I can achieve that using:

```
def test( name ) { 
    g = "${name}"
    println g instanceof GString // is true
    println g.toString()   
}
test("Oscar")
```

I *think* I know the reason but I would like to know for sure.

Comment: A workaround with GStringTemplate ( or something like that ) but not a real answer. Here if you don't mind reading in spanish :P http://www.javamexico.org/foros/groovy/%C2%BFpor_que_esto_no_funciona_este_gstring_como_lo_espero  and  http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/text/GStringTemplateEngine.html

Answer (score 1):

Since you declare both g and s to be strings, the toString() method will simply return their values.  There is no actual evaluation of Groovy code (this could be dangerous in quite a few scenarios, if you think about it).

I think whatever you're trying to achieve might be better accomplished via closures?

Answer (score 1):

the reason is that Groovy can't ensure it still has access to the context where the java.lang.String has been created e.g.

```
def myFunction()  {
  def a = 1
  return '${a}'
}

GString.EMPTY.plus (myFunction()) // no access to local variable a anymore!
```

thus, no evaluation happens on a given java.lang.String on a GString.plus call.